# Prove that there is unique group of order 35 up to isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have shown that any group of order 35 is cyclic.
I don't know what to do next.

EDIT: I am not asking how to show that any group of order 35 is cyclic, just trying to show that that implies its unique

Comment: If you have shown that, you are done. There is only one cyclic group for each order!

Answer (score 1):

(i) prove the Sylow subgroup $S$ of order $7$ is unique (Sylow's third theorem).

(ii) deduce $S$ is normal in $G$.

(iii) prove that $G$ is a semidirect product of $S$ with its Sylow $5$-subgroup $T$.

(iv) Show that the only action of $T$ on $S$ is trivial.

(v) prove this semidirect product is direct.

Answer (score 0):

In a much more general sense you have the following result,

> **Result:** If $G$ is a group of order $pq$ for some primes $p$, $q$ such that $p>q$ and $q\not| \;(p-1)$ then $G \cong\Bbb Z/pq\Bbb Z$.

So every group of order $pq$ satisfying the above conditions will be isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/pq\Bbb Z$ and hence upto isomorphism only one such group exists.